# Combobox Relation Table Did Not Show The Data

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I've tried to add relation, to show the data on combobox and datagridview. I've tried this code below

```
Private Sub LoadSemester()
    Me.OpenConn()

    Dim dSet As New DataSet

    Dim sql1 As String = "SELECT * FROM tbl_semester"
    Dim comm1 As New SqlClient.SqlCommand(sql1, cnn)
    Dim daSemester As SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter

    Dim sql2 As String = "SELECT * FROM tbl_mk"
    Dim comm2 As New SqlClient.SqlCommand(sql2, cnn)
    Dim daMK As SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter

    daMK = New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(comm2)
    dSet.Clear()
    daMK.Fill(dSet, "tbl_mk")

    daSemester = New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(comm1)
    dSet.Clear()
    daSemester.Fill(dSet, "tbl_semester")
    dSet.Relations.Add("relation", dSet.Tables("tbl_semester").Columns("id_pk"), dSet.Tables("tbl_pk").Columns("id_pk"))

    With cmbSemester
        .DataSource = dSet.Tables("tbl_semester")
        .DisplayMember = "semester"
        .ValueMember = "id_semester"
        .SelectedIndex = 0
    End With

    'my datagridview here
End Sub
```

But it displayed nothing. But when I deleted the 'dSet.Relations.Add("relation", dSet.Tables("tbl_semester").Columns("id_pk"), dSet.Tables("tbl_pk").Columns("id_pk"))' the combobox showed the data.

I figured out maybe the problem is the dSet.Relation code. FYI, I am using SQLServer 2005 and VS Express 2012.

Comment: I have tried this `dSet.Relations.Add(New DataRelation("relation", dSet.Tables("tbl_semester").Columns("id_pk"), dSet.Tables("tbl_pk").Columns("id_pk")))`

but not working too

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Thanks for it, @JohnSaunders. Now can you help me fix my errors, please

Comment: If I had an answer, I'd tell you.